# Building more diverse local Organized Play RPG community

Tags: organized-play

How do I build a more diverse local RPG community? Currently, there's several Organized Play RPG communities in my closest metro region (West Coast, USA). The largest OP group has several thousand members and a very broad, diverse demographic base with members from almost every social facet of urban life.

There are a few other OP groups that are far smaller and insular. From my observation, these groups are almost entirely ethnically white, middle-aged men. These groups range from 50-200 members at most.

I am an active member in multiple Organized Play groups, and there is a glaring difference in membership and demographics.

How do I help build an Organized Play community that doesn't become insular and homogenous? I don't know if a reformation approach is helpful or appropriate for these groups, but I'm not willing to accept the status quo.

Comment: So you're looking here for an answers from users who've had actual success in building a more diverse local RPG community (or similar project, I guess), or answers that come from users who have heard how this was done? That is, answers shouldn't be just a list of suggestions that might work, right? (That is, that's how this question meets the site's guidelines—and it might be useful to remind folks of that in the question. If you're just looking for untested suggestions that might work, that's better suited to a forum.)

Comment: Reminder that [answers to this question should follow our subjective citation guidelines](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/1204), which means they should be **backed up by experience** (your own or someone else's) of how your solution has worked out in actual practice. “We did this thing and it resulted in these specific outcomes”, for example. Answers that suggest a solution without being able to cite how it's worked out may be removed. Note that explaining _in what way_ it worked out is more valuable than stating simply whether or not it worked out well.

Answer (score 2):

I did not grow up in the US, so this is my experience from Europe. It may or may not apply to your specific diversity situation, you will probably need additional specific advice.

But I think it's a bare minimum to not exclude *any* people:

## Limit influence of time and money spent on the game

Make sure that the time spent outside the gaming arena does not influence the gaming experience. What does that mean? Not everybody is a nerdy rich white kid. Those can easily buy more books, read them all day, compare tables, optimize their character. Other people may not have that kind of money or even time. Maybe they have to help in the house or even have a job. So make sure that "we play from 3 PM to 7 PM" means that only actions between 3 pm and 7 pm actually count. That is largely a system issue. Lets take some prime examples of how to exclude people that aren't rich white nerds: Play D&D or Shadowrun (or lots of others like them). Both are great systems and I love playing them, but in both, one thing is very obvious: the more books you buy and the more time you spend reading them and comparing options, the better and more powerful your character will be. With those systems, you spend time and money outside the gaming table to "buy" you a more powerful character at the gaming table. For people that don't have that time or money, that sucks. I would not play in a group with a bunch of super optimized characters and my "I read the basic rules on the bus to work" character. I'd rather not play that game at all.

For me personally, a counter-example was Vampire, because it had very simple rules. It was in no way "rules light" or simple in itself, but it had very little complexity as in the various things to pick for your character did not interact that much. In theory you could read just the part about your character and you would not be worse off than somebody buying and reading all the books that existed.

So to sum this up: don't make money or time (and time to spare *is* money) decide who has fun at the gaming table. A game should depend on the actions and decisions in the game, not the real life situation outside. It should *best case* be a fantastic escape from a harsh reality, not a harsh reminder that you cannot escape that reality.

In my experience, even if you start out divers (for example all kids in a class for an after school project), if you don't follow this advice, the group will self-select into a pool of people with money and time to blow. And most likely in our society, that's white kids or white single guys.

---

<sup>Again, this is the bare minimum, you will need additional advice on how to even recruit a divers group of people specific to your locale. Maybe we should make this into a community wiki, so in the end we have one big list of advice?</sup>

Comment: Feel free to let me know why you think it's not useful.

Comment: I think none of this really applies to an organized play scenario..

Comment: @WeckarE. I don‘t understand, why wouldn’t it? Don’t you make characters and play games with them? Or is it implied that it’s always premades? Where I live it’s bring your own character.

Comment: @nvoigt for example official organized D&D is core + 1 book already, and you give D&D as example of systems where buying more helps. Well, in D&D it doesn't.

Comment: @Mołot Again, I don't understand. If you can bring one additional book to pick rules for your character from, surely a well stocked bookshelf to pick from and time to read all the books to make the best choice is a lot better than not having those options and going with the free PDF of the basic rules?

Comment: I think a clarification of what "organized play" is in order (At least a link to a resource). In a broader context, this is sound advice.